# SSH login@ip@gateway through config+VSCode

Tags: linux, networking, macos, ssh

I can successfully connect from my macbook+VPN to my corporative cloud server through ssh with this command (passwordless, using my id_ed25519 key):

`ssh login@ip@gateway -A`

But I need to connect to this server inside VSCode. I created server's config like this:

```
Host servername
    HostName ip
    User login
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyJump gateway
```

and it does not work, I'm sure doing smth wrong.
After I pressing "connect", VSCode requires "Please enter server host name".

The way from ChatGPT:

```
Host servername
    HostName ip
    User login
    HostKeyAlias servername
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p login@gateway -A
    ForwardAgent yes
```

How should I create ssh-config to repeat my successful connection string ?

Note:
ip is smth like "123.123.222.3".
gateway is smth like "v00gateway01.corp.company.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this ssh_config:

```
Host servername
    HostName gateway
    User login@ip
    ForwardAgent yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wtite the path to your ssh key in this config (I'm not sure about syntax)

Comment: Not working. I believe -A option is choosing my single possible key automatically

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).